# Create a hash in Rails where key and value are values from a table's fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a hash that will be passed to [`options_for_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) as the container.

The select options are table records, with the key being the `name` field, and value being the `id` field.

So far I have this

```
>> User.select([:id, :name]).index_by(&:name)  # or .index_by { |u| u.name }
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT id, name FROM `users`
{
     "Name One" => #<User:0x007fc183752a78> {
          :id => 1,
        :name => "Name One"
    },
    "Name Two" => #<User:0x007fc1837525f0> {
          :id => 2,
        :name => "Name Two"
    }
}
```

Instead I want

```
{
    "Name One" => 1,
    "Name Two" => 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following does what you want in a efficient way (actually is a modified version of `index_by`)

```
 User.select([:id, :name]).reduce({}) { |acc, x| acc.merge(x[:name] => x[:id]) }
```

Comment: very slick coding!

Comment: I mostly understand this code, but do not grok it.  Any chance you could explain how this works in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
users = {
  "Name One" => {
    :id => 1,
    :name => "Name One"
  },
  "Name Two" =>  {
    :id => 2,
    :name => "Name Two"
  }
}

p Hash[users.map { |k,v| [k, v[:id] ]}]
# => {"Name One"=>1, "Name Two"=>2}
```

You can wrap the `Hash[ ... ]` part around your `User.select(...).index_by(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, you may be looking for a `collect`

```
User.all.collect { |u| [u.id, u.name] }
```

Which will return an array, but if you look at `options_for_select` it accepts both hashes and arrays

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Rails has a FormOptionsHelper for this: [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_from_collection_for_select)

```
options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :name)
```

As seen in the RoR Guide for Form Helpers under ["Option Tags from a Collection of Arbitrary Objects"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-tags-from-a-collection-of-arbitrary-objects).

Even better is to use [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) instead of [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) for your form.

```
-  = f.select :user_id, options_from_collection_for_select(User.all, :id, :name), include_blank: true
+  = f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true
```